# eval-buffer: Symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, slime

I am trying to run Emacs with slime and clisp on windows. Currently I am setting up my init-file so that I can run SLIME.

```el
(setq inferior-lisp-program “home/gage/bin/clisp/full/lisp.exe
-B home/gage/bin/clisp/full
-M home/gage/bin/clisp/full/lispinit.mem
-ansi -q”)
(add-to-list ‘load-path “home/gage/bin/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/”)
(require ‘slime)
(slime-setup)
```

I run `eval-buffer` and this error pops up.

```
eval-buffer: Symbol's value as variable is void: “home/gage/bin/clisp/full/lisp\.exe
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes. I just tried:

```el
(setq foo “bar”)
```

and got the same error. This command worked for me:

```el
(setq foo "bar")
```

So you need to change all instances of `“` to `"` (and probably also `‘` to `'`).